# SELECT in MySQL doesn't return a row when a field is NULL and a filter LIKE '%'

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with a field:
 - `field1 (Varchar(10)) Default NULL;`

When I run this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE '%';
```

That query does not return rows where `Field1 IS NULL;`

Why `NULL` it is not considered as any value?

What solution do I have? I don't know the default value of the fields in a table to make a query.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table` should do. LIKE `%` means you are getting all rows except nuLL

Comment: I have a form with a filter input name, and I need my query to work when that field is left empty: SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE '%$_POST["name"]';

Comment: when that field is left empty by user input, You should simply ignore that condition in your where clause. This will make your query more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` is an unknown value or missing value. So use **`COALESCE`** function to make the null value to a non-null value.

**Query**

```
select * from `table`
where coalesce(`field1`, '') like '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *FROM table_name where column_name is null
```

try this code.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `LIKE '%'`, that means something like «any string with any character», and `NULL` is not a string.

If you want rows that only contains `null`, you must write :

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 IS NULL;`

But if you want all rows, you can remove the `WHERE` part, and write this:

`SELECT * FROM table`